# Popup Window is not work in my activity

Tags: android, performance, popupwindow

I have implemented Popup Window in one Application. I have sample code of [This](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/android-tutorial/how-to-create-popups-in-android-2/#comment-2236). If I implement this code in my activity than it's not Working. so i cant found my Error. can any one help me.

**Unlock_hud.java:**

```
inf = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    myview = inf.inflate(R.layout.unlock_launcher, null);
    receive = (Button) myview.findViewById(R.id.receive1);
    reject = (Button) myview.findViewById(R.id.reject12);
    slidehandlebutton= (Button) myview.findViewById(R.id.slidehandlebutton);
    slidehandlebutton.setOnClickListener(this);


    Handler ha = new Handler();
    ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService("activity");
            List<RunningTaskInfo> list_running = mActivityManager
                    .getRunningTasks(2147483647);
            List<RecentTaskInfo> list_recent = mActivityManager
                    .getRecentTasks(2147483647, 1);

            Log.d("main", "Running: " + list_running.get(0).topActivity);
            Log.d("main", "Recent: " + list_recent.get(0).baseIntent);
        /*  Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
            startActivity(homeIntent);*/
            // Log.d("main", "Free Memory: " + getUsedMemorySize());
            prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());



        }

    }, 500)
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("main", "Ondestroy");
    // lock.reenableKeyguard();
    if (!call_flag && wm2 != null) {
        if (receive_flag) {
            if (isaddView) {
                wm2.removeView(myview);
            }

        } else {
            wm2.removeView(new_view);
        }

        edit.putBoolean("flag", false);
        edit.commit();
        call_flag = true;
        if (CheckMissCall.bmp != null) {
            CheckMissCall.bmp.recycle();
            CheckMissCall.bmp = null;


        }

    }

}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {

    case R.id.slidehandlebutton:
         if (p != null)
               showPopup(Unlock_hud.this, p);
        break;


    }
}

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

       int[] location = new int[2];
       Button button = (Button)myview. findViewById(R.id.slidehandlebutton);

       // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
       // location[0] = x, location[1] = y.
       button.getLocationOnScreen(location);

       //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
       p = new Point();
       p.x = location[0];
       p.y = location[1];
    }

private void showPopup(Context context, Point p2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int popupWidth = 180;
       int popupHeight = 80;

       // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
       LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.popup);
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

       // Creating the PopupWindow
       final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(c);
       popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
       popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
       popup.setFocusable(true);

       // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
       int OFFSET_X =-200;
       int OFFSET_Y =20;

       // Clear the default translucent background
       popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

       // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
       popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);

       // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
       Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.stop);
       close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
           popup.dismiss();
         }
       });
    }
```

Now i found error In ( CONTEXT )

```
 LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Where did you define your `context` variable? And which type of error do you have?

Comment: there are no any error. is main problem @G.T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use your code. But it seems ok.

Full code snippet of `Activity`

```
public class TestPopupActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    //The "x" and "y" position of the "Show Button" on screen.
    Point p;
    private LinearLayout holder;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View myView;
    private Button btn_show;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       holder  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.holder);
       inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_layout, null);
       btn_show = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.show_popup);
       btn_show.setOnClickListener(this);
       holder.addView(myView);
    }

    // Get the x and y position after the button is draw on screen
    // (It's important to note that we can't get the position in the onCreate(),
    // because at that stage most probably the view isn't drawn yet, so it will return (0, 0))
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

       int[] location = new int[2];
      /* Button button = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.show_popup);*/

       // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
       // location[0] = x, location[1] = y.
       btn_show.getLocationOnScreen(location);

       //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
       p = new Point();
       p.x = location[0];
       p.y = location[1];
    }

    // The method that displays the popup.
    private void showPopup(Activity context, Point p) {
       int popupWidth = 200;
       int popupHeight = 150;

       // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
       LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

       // Creating the PopupWindow
       final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
       popup.setContentView(layout);
       popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
       popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
       popup.setFocusable(true);

       // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
       int OFFSET_X = 30;
       int OFFSET_Y = 30;

       // Clear the default translucent background
       popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

       // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
       popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);

       // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
       Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
       close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
           popup.dismiss();
         }
       });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.show_popup:
            if (p != null)
                   showPopup(TestPopupActivity.this, p);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    }
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Further ther is same problem. popup is not display @kaushik

Comment: have you set `onClickListener` for that button `slidehandlebutton`

Comment: ya i have set onclickListner

Comment: there is no error in debug. check my update question code. @kaushik

Comment: `slidehandlebutton` is visible or not