# POPUP window showing in android

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

i have created a button in android and when clicking it would show the popup window..but the code doesnot work like that..it has no errors but not showing popup window...please helpme..here is my code
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final RelativeLayout objrl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myrl);      
    final Button objButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    objButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupWindow objPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(objrl, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);                
            objPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.drawable.background2);
            objPopupWindow.showAtLocation(objButton, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 10, 10);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Check this Andwer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18867300/1160282

Comment: oh..!! i havent understand why you strickoff the objects ...??? plese explain

Comment: I just formatted your code nothing else.

Comment: ok...please tell the error in my code,...its not showing popup window... @silentkiller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18867300/1160282 sample code.

Comment: i did my sample in reference to that code only...but its not showing..????:-( what is wrong in that...please explain..@SilentKiller

Comment: @YurekaMathammalRajendran : u can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777238/popup-window-is-not-work-in-my-activity/24777553#24777553)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this : `objPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupButton, 0, 0);`

or try this http://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-popupwindow-example-in-listview.html

Comment: juz now tried...but not yet working..:-( please help

Answer (score 0):

```
 PopupWindow popupWindowDogs = popupWindowDogs();

called below function where they want ::-





 public PopupWindow popupWindowDogs() {

        // initialize a pop up window type
        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);

        // the drop down list is a list view
        ListView listViewDogs = new ListView(this);

        // set our adapter and pass our pop up window contents
        listViewDogs.setAdapter(dogsAdapter(popUpContents));

        // set the item click listener
        listViewDogs.setOnItemClickListener(new DogsDropdownOnItemClickListener());

        // some other visual settings
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.setWidth(250);
        popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        // set the list view as pop up window content
        popupWindow.setContentView(listViewDogs);

        return popupWindow;
    }
```

Comment: i just want to show a popup on clicking a button...please help

Answer (score 0):

I've found some strange stuff in your codes

- You've specified WRAP_CONTENT but haven't specified its content at all
- Pass a drawable as animation style to the `setAnimationStyle` method.

In my opinion if you specify a valid animation style and a content view, It should appear.

Comment: @YurekaMathammalRajendran You shouldn't pass a drawble to that method. Also specify a content view for it by `setContentView`

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this code inside the *OnClickListener*
`objPopupWindow.setContentView(objrl);`